# Сохранение пропорций изображения при изменения ширины

Tags: css, swiper, swiper.js

Сделал слайдер на Swiper JS.
Хотелось бы, чтобы при изменении ширины экрана, пропорционально изменялась бы и высота картинки.

Как это можно сделать?

Ссылка на слайдер:

```
[https://codepen.io/oykhflhm-the-sans/pen/LYMYxZj][1]
```

Comment: Возможно тебе поможет `css` свойство `aspect-ratio` - https://doka.guide/css/aspect-ratio/

Comment: да, в итоге так и сделал, спасибо! Можете отметить это как ответ, поставлю галочку)

Comment: Спасибо, оформил ответом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Хотелось бы, чтобы при изменении ширины экрана, пропорционально изменялась бы и высота картинки.

Есть `css` свойство `aspect-ratio` https://doka.guide/css/aspect-ratio/

Если правильно подобрать соотношение сторон - все масштабирование возьмет на себя браузер...